# The mongo can't show its correct size of database in terminal

Tags: mongodb

I use pymongo to save the data that I've crawled by scrapy,and when I use `show dbs` command to check the database in terminal.It looks like this

```
  > show dbs
EPGD___test                 0.000GB
EPGD_closetest              0.000GB
Testinsert                  0.000GB
local                       0.000GB
sta                         0.000GB
stackoverflow               0.000GB
stackoverflow_test          0.000GB
stackoverflow_test_morning  0.000GB
temptest1                   0.000GB
```

As you can see ,the size of database `EPGD_closetest` is `0.000GB`,and in the GUI `mongoHub`,there are also no collections can be found in the database.
[enter image description here][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDZI1.png.But when I use the following command `use EPGD_closetest` and `db.EPGD_test.find()` and I can see there are datas in the database.And I can also get it using pymongo.

The code when I save datas to mongo by pymongo:

```
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
    valid = True
    for data in item:
        if not data:
            valid = False
            raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
    if valid:
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        log.msg("Item wrote to MongoDB database {}, collection {}, at host {}, port {}".format(
        settings['MONGODB_DB'],
        settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION'],
        settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
        settings['MONGODB_PORT']))
    return item
```

The code when I read datas from mongo by pymongo:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()

db = client.EPGD_closetest
collection = db.EPGD_test

print collection.find().count()
print collection.find_one({"taxID" : [ "9606" ]})
```

The result as below:

```
299
{u'familyID_url': u'http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/paralogfamily/getInfor.jsp?familyID=50144', u'description': [u'lectin, mannose-binding, 1'], u'symbol': [u'LMAN1'], u'taxID': [u'9606'], u'taxID_url': [u'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?mode=Info&id=9606'], u'familyID': [u'50144'], u'genID': [u'3998'], u'genID_url': u'http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/gene/geneinfor.jsp?geneID=3998', u'_id': ObjectId('56fb6c11c75c1608bde3293c'), u'chromosome': [u'18']}
```

So can anyone tell me what's wrong with my mongo?

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly normal... Because data is very small in your collection so it is showing almost 0.000GB of data. You can put more data to see the changes...

You can also use `db.stats()` to check data stats of db. Here is the result of `db.stats()`

```
{
    "db" : "nxb",
    "collections" : 2,
    "objects" : 5,
    "avgObjSize" : 133.8,
    "dataSize" : 669,
    "storageSize" : 40960,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "indexes" : 2,
    "indexSize" : 40960,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there is still a question that I can't see the data in my mongoHub.Can you tell why does this happened?Thank you!